# LINQ query crashes when 0 rows found

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

My query makes my program crash runtime, if the query doesnt find any rows in the database it crashes and throws a notsupportedexception on the query, if it does find one it keeps on going as it should.. My way of solving this is to put a try around it all and when it catches an exception do what i want it to do if there are 0 rows but i feel there must be a better way of solving this

edit: Tried firstordefault doesnt work

```
var test = (from a in conn.vaccineringar
            where a.Personnummer.Equals(personNummer) && a.Vaccin.Equals(vaccinId)
            select a).First();

if(test != null)
{
    return "No can do";
}
```

Comment: So... what's the question? Seems like you already have the answer.

Comment: You should paste the exception message you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549141(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `First()`:

> Returns the first element of a sequence that satisfies a specified condition or a default value if no such element is found.

```
var test = (from a in conn.vaccineringar
            where a.Personnummer.Equals(personNummer) && a.Vaccin.Equals(vaccinId)
            select a).FirstOrDefault();

if(test != null)
{
    return "No can do";
}
```

Also, you should use `==` instead of `Equals` calls:

```
var test = (from a in conn.vaccineringar
            where a.Personnummer == personNummer && a.Vaccin == vaccinId
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: tried it  doesnt work

Comment: Try with `==` instead of `Equals`.

Comment: and that is because you cannot send in an evaluation method to a `where` linq because it cannot evaluate

Answer (score 1):

You could try `FirstOrDefault`. This method returns  the first element that matches your criteria and if there isn't any element it returns the default value, which in your case is `null`. So this way you will not get any error.

```
var test = (from a in conn.vaccineringar
            where a.Personnummer.Equals(personNummer) && a.Vaccin.Equals(vaccinId)
            select a).FirstOrDefault();

if(test != null)
{
    return "No can do";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are using `.First()` which states: `System.InvalidOperationException` if
the source sequence is empty.

Try using `.FirstOrDefault()` instead

Comment: what type is your result ? the one you are trying to get in the `var` variable ?

Comment: the object type, vaccineringar

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try .FirstOrDefault() instead of .First().

This will provide the first value or a default (presumably null in this case).

Comment: tried it doesnt work